# jq replace substring in value

Tags: bash, jq

This the output of my curl

```
{
  "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
  "id": "240937",
  "self": "https://placeholder.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/240937",
  "key": "placeholder-355",
  "fields": {
    "description": "We need the following page layout changes made (for all user profiles unless specified in front of the item):\n\n# Display {{TestAccount__c}} field on the account object underneath the *Pricing Group* field\n# Display {{blng__LegalEntity__c}} field that sits on {{Order Product}} to be visible on *Order* as well as *Contract* objects _(position doesn’t matter). Read only is fine as long as that works on SF reports if we need to bring this attribute in_\n# Display {{blng__LegalEntity__c}} field that sits on *Invoice Lines* to be visible on the *Invoice* object _(position doesn’t matter). Read only is fine as long as that works on SF reports if we need to bring this attribute in_\n# Display ‘*Notes*’ section on the credit request page - copy the one that exists on the contract object e.g. (sample below)\n!image-20220714-021135.png|width=50%!\n# -Display- *-Agent-* -field on contract object to enable users to see if account has an agent or not- → already in production (not needed)\n# Change default options for *tasks* - the default subjects are:\n#* Call\n#* Send Letter\n#* Send Quote\n#* Other\n# Need to update to the following:\n#* Call\n#* Video Call\n#* Face to Face Meeting\n# Add in *Contact hierarchy* functionality in Salesforce\n## Anyone can update the ‘Reports to’ field\n## Show the following fields on the hierarchy page"
  }
}
```

With jq I'm getting json

```
 jq --raw-output '.fields.description' jira-story.json
```

Result:

```
# Display *Pricing Group* field
# Display *Contract*
# Change default options for *tasks* - the default subjects are:
#* Call
#* Send Letter
#* Send Quote
#* Other
# Need to update to the following:
#* Call
#* Video Call
#* Face to Face Meeting
# Add in *Contact hierarchy* 
## Anyone can update the ‘Reports to’ field
## Show the following fields on the hierarchy page
```

I want it nicely format it as

```
### Display *Pricing Group* field
### Display *Contract*
### Change default options for *tasks* - the default subjects are:
- Call
- Send Letter
- Send Quote
- Other
### Need to update to the following:
- Call
- Video Call
- Face to Face Meeting
### Add in *Contact hierarchy* 
- Anyone can update the ‘Reports to’ field
- Show the following fields on the hierarchy page
```

How can I replace the value in a jq before the output?
"#*" to "-" or "##" to "-" and "#" to "###"

Comment: `.fields.description | gsub("\n#[#*]";"\n-") | gsub("\n# ","\n### ")` ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to perform the substitution in jq, you can pipe the output to sed:

```
jq -r '.fields.description' | sed 's/^#[#*]/-/;s/^#/###/'
```

If you really must do it with a single jq expression, then what user [jhnc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10971581/jhnc) wrote in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73202129/jq-replace-substring-in-value#comment129283694_73202129):

> `jq -r '.fields.description | gsub("\n#[#*]";"\n-") | gsub("\n# ","\n### ")'`